# Searching for a name when missing some chars of it

Tags: google-search

I was wondering if there existed a way to search for the name of somebody when some letters of its name were missing. For instance, let's say we know the profession of somebody but only have the first letter of his first name and the first and last letter of his name and his profession :

> E. WN, British actress that played in Harry Potter.
>   Which would be Emma Watson.

In my memories one could use `*` when a word was missing but what about some chars?

I tried :

```
"British actress E." W*N
```

But I'm not sure that * stands for several missing chars.

Answer (score 1):

From [Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)

> **Search for wildcards or unknown words**
>
> Put a * in your word or phrase where you want to leave a placeholder. For example, "largest * in the world".

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
"british actress emma" wa*on
```

or

```
"british actress emma w*n"
```

or

```
british actress emma w*n
```

Google can guess missing characters if it has some solid base like first name

Comment: Yeah, actually I was looking for a general in the foreign legion and I only have his trigram btx, with b his first name and t and x the first letter and last letter of his last name around the year 2000s

Comment: @ThePassenger thats not much information to begin with :(

Comment: @ThePassenger try maybe: [bing search engine](https://www.bing.com/search?q=legion+%22General+B.+T%22*x&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=legion+%22general+b.+t%22*&sc=1-22&sk=&cvid=FD17EA4A14C24A179604B4BA14DF255F)